# Laravel is throwing Route [/profileUpdate/update] not defined error

Tags: php, laravel

Good night, I'm working with a new laravel route, but when I try to put the href, it throws me
an Route [/profileUpdate/update] not defined error.

The web.php route:

```php
Route::post('/profileUpdate/update', 'ProfileController@updateProfile')->name('profile.update');
```

The profilePage.blade.php code:

```php
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"href="{{ route('/profileUpdate/update') }}">Edit your profile</button>
```

Can anyone help me, please? I tried to find the error some days ago and I'm need of help. Thanks!

Comment: `route()` function uses route name

Answer (score 3):

The `route()` helper takes the name of the route as the argument. So your link should be

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-info"href="{{ route('profile.update') }}">Edit your profile</a>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, that worked for the error. But it don't redirects me to profileUpdate.blade when i click on it :/

Comment: It's like an useless button, it does nothing and stays in the same page.

Comment: Ah. I see. Please change it from a <button> to an <a> tag. I'll update the answer as well.

Comment: Just noticed that it's a POST route. If it's in a form, don't forget to mark the button as type="submit" so that it submits the form and makes the post request.

Comment: I changed the <button> tag to a <a>, and changed also type to submit, but it throws another error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. In web.php it haves the POST method and not the GET 

Comment: On your form element, add ```method=POST``` so that it sends a POST request instead of a GET request.